# create objects in member function

Tags: c++

The header is defined like

```
class MyClass_A;
typedef map<string, MyClass_A*> MyMap
typedef vector<MyClass_A*>      MyList

class MyClass_A
{
  // define some functions
}

class MyClass_B
{
public:
  void check(){ //create MyClass_A pointer to store in myMap and myList }
private:
  MyMap   myMap;
  MyList  myList;
}
```

The main function is like

```
int main()
{
  MyClass_B class_B;
  class_B.check();
  /*
    do some works
  */
}
```

I want to define MyClass_A objects in check which is a member function in MyClass_B. And the objects would not destruct until end the main function.

I have tried some methods but the objects would remove when leave the check member function. Is there any solution?

Comment: *the objects would remove when leave the check member function* -- uh, as far as i know, in C++ there is no garbage collection like in Java (where you could lose an instance if you never reference it). at least, could you give a clue on what *do some works* do and how `void check()` works. it might give some insight.

Comment: You should create these objects with `new`, so that they dont die when you leave the function `MyClass_B::check()`...

Comment: The names `_MAP` and `_LIST`, aside from being unconventional, are not legal in C++.  Names that start with an underscore must not have a second underscore or a capital letter as their second character.

Comment: Objects declared in `check` function will be destroyed as soon as the function's execution is complete. To do what you are trying to do, you need to declare that object outside `check` function.

Comment: @A.S.H: It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing raw pointers, use smart pointers:

```
class MyClass_B
{
public:
  void check(){
    //create MyClass_A pointer to store in myMap and myList
    Ptr_A obj = std::make_shared<MyClass_A>();
    myMap["hello"] = obj;
    myList.push_back(obj);
  }

private:
  typedef std::shared_ptr<MyClass_A> Ptr_A;
  std::map<std::string, Ptr_A> myMap;
  std::list<Ptr_A> myList;
}
```

Now the lifetimes of `MyClass_A` instances are managed automatically.  When an instance of `MyClass_B` is destroyed, the objects it contains will be destroyed also.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it possible to declare MyClass_A pointer inside or out the check function to this problem?

Comment: @ycliu: I don't know what you're asking now.

Comment: Just use `map<string, MyClass_A*>` instead of `map<string, MyClass_A>`. And the problem is solved by using `MyClass_A* tmp = new MyClass_A`.

Comment: @ycliu: You can do that but then you will need to be very careful not to leak memory.